# How to stop toolbar title shrink and grow when using CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, xml

I want similar behavior to my toolbar title like shown in below image.

[image]

As you can see It's title fade out and disappear completely when it's fully scrolled. When it's scrolled up toolbar title comes to write place. This how my app tool bar title works.

[image]

As you can see my tool bar title does not get disappear. If it is possible I would like to make title to fade out without even moving down when scrolling down. Here's my source code.

**Layout file**

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/main_background_color">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/camera_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/customer_registration_toolbar_image"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

          <!-- All scroll able contain here -->

       </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Activity**

```
public class CustomerRegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer_registration);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        toolbar.setTitle("Customer Registration");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Please point out what I need do to get the behavior I described.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the answers. I achieved what I want by adding `expandedTitleTextAppearance` attribute.

First add `app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TransparentText"` to `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

And Create TransparentText file in style folder like below.

```
<style name="TransparentText">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00000000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">0sp</item>
</style>
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can specify in xml itself like below,

```
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                    app:title="@string/title"
                    app:titleTextColor="@color/white" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

and set this in your nested scroll view

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:behavior_overlapTop="@dimen/some_value_to_place_title_under_button" // eg 50 dp, 70dp
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
```

You should specify the title in toolbar itself
and remove java code for setting title

```
  app:title="@string/title"
```

and also you need to import the namespace to the root view of the layout

```
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Or in java code set title by

```
 getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title");
```

Comment: What happen to image view. Where should I place that ?

Comment: Or much easy way is to place the image inside the CollapsingToolBar layout, as background @ChathurangaShanJayarathna

Comment: @ChathurangaShanJayarathna like `android:background="drawable/your_image"`

Answer (score 0):

I think bellow mentioned code can solve your problems.

```
collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleColor(Color.parseColor("#00FFFFFF"));
```

Comment: Not quite what i want but I this showed the correct path. thanks